# Definition could not be found error compiling ClassReference in CSS file to Swf file

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I am compiling my css files to swf files and loading them at run time. I have no problem compiling these and using ClassReference statements most of the time:

```
.miniCashLadderGridStyle
{
    color : #2a2a2a;
    backgroundAlpha : 0;
    borderSkin : ClassReference("mx.skins.ProgrammaticSkin");
    headerSortSeparatorSkin : ClassReference("mx.skins.ProgrammaticSkin");
    horizontalSeparatorSkin : ClassReference("company.assets.GridHorzDivLine");
    verticalSeparatorSkin : ClassReference("company.assets.GridVertDivLine");
}
```

That works fine. The assets come from a seperate swc, However this:

```
header-background-skin : ClassReference("company.view.grid.skin.HeaderBackground");
```

Does not work. The difference is that the HeaderBackground is a class in the same project as the css file. That does compiel fine if I move the style into my mxml file though.

I wonder if the compiler uses different source paths when compiling the css fiels or something.

This is in FlashBuilder 4 build 269271 SDK 13963

Comment: bug filed here: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-26030

Answer (score 2):

Because the skin class you referenced has not been compiled into the application if you not use it in other place, so a run time class not found error will happened when the style SWF is applied. By avoiding this error, you can enforce the skin classes to be compiled into your application. For example:

```
<s:Application>
    import company.view.grid.skin.HeaderBackground;
    private var referrenceEnforcer:Array = [HeaderBackground];
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you compile css to swf in Flex/Flash builder, it runs mxmlc without the project's build path, so the sources are not visible to the compiler. [The old bug filed 2 years ago](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-11925)

The workaround is to place the packages needed to the same folder where the css is (even a symlink is enough). The compiler would see the files & compile them to classes appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

Flex supports external CSS style sheets. To apply a style sheet to the current document and its child documents, use the source property of the  tag. External style sheet files should be in the folder that contains your MXML source files. By default, this is the src folder in your MXML project.

Note: You should try to limit the number of style sheets used in an application, and set the style sheet only at the top-level document in the application (the document that contains the  tag). If you set a style sheet in a child document, unexpected results can occur.

The following example defines two CSS class selectors in an external CSS file called external.css. You use an external CSS file in a Flex application by specifying its path and file name in the source property of the  tag.
Example:
External CSS file

```
/* An external CSS file */
.solidBorder
{
    borderStyle: "solid";
}

.solidBorderPaddedVertically
{
    borderStyle: "solid";
    paddingTop: 12px;
    paddingBottom: 12px;
}
```

MXML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application 
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    width="150" height="140" 
    viewSourceURL="src/StylesExternal/index.html"

>
    <mx:Style source="styles/external.css" />

    <mx:VBox styleName="solidBorder">

        <mx:Button label="Submit"/>
    </mx:VBox>

    <mx:VBox styleName="solidBorderPaddedVertically">
        <mx:Button label="Submit"/>
    </mx:VBox>

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: That would probably work but that would compile the styles into the swf. We compile css files into their own swf file and load them at run time. It is compiling this style module that causes the issues.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling the CSS, provide the swf of the module in the library-path parameter of the compiler and he'll see the class.

Answer (score 0):

Try just right clicking the CSS in the Package Explorer of FlashBuilder 4, then take compile CSS to SWF. That seemed to fix it for me.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution for this issue
http://volokh.com.ua/blog/2011/06/14/my-fix-for-classreference-in-nested-css-file-compiled-to-swf-causes-error/